# Same modal from different states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

I'd like to achieve that
when a modal dialog pops up then the background will be the last active page.
I'd like to organize my code around states, so I would prefer those kind of solutions which use it.

Scenario 1: 
Given a navbar with an info button which opens a modal dialog
And I am in 'login' state/page 
When I click on the info button
Then the background page remains 'login'
And the modal dialog pops up

Scenario 2: 
Given a navbar with an info button which opens a modal dialog
And I am in 'settings' state/page 
When I click on the info button
Then the background page remains 'settings'
And the modal dialog pops up

Scenario 3: 
Given the modal dialog is open
And the previous state/page was 'login'
When I click away
Then the active page/state will be 'login'

Here is my plunker code which works (sort of 'cause it does not go to another state after dismiss) for only one state:
http://plnkr.co/edit/HfKWT5?p=preview

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Your layout makes it look like you are writing a sonnet.  Unfortunately, it doesn't read that way. Next time, please use better formatting for your question. You can use lists (numbered or bulleted) and it will read much better.

Comment: It looks like someone has bumped into this problem too:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/123